# If the magnetic force doesn't change the speed of a moving charge can it be thought of as an elastic scattering?

Tags: forces, particle-physics, magnetic-fields, charge, centripetal-force

If magnetic force is a  force only on a moving charge that doesn't change its speed even though it changes its velocity can it be thought of as an elastic scattering from a circular wall created by the field? I am asking this because for me is confusing how a perpendicular force cannot change the magnitude of the particle velocity if the Pithagorean theorem states that it should be like so.(The angles of this scattering should be very small to mimic a circle.)

[image]

Comment: In truth, it is elastic scattering with the magnetic field itself (at quantum level virtual photons exchanged with the magnetic field), Mathematics being what it is maybe your simulation could be  a transform of that scattering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A magnetic field aligns the magnetic dipole of the charge. The charge emits a photon with two reactions:

1. the photon momentum deflects the charge a little from its straight trajectory.
2. the spin gets de-aligned again.

This repeats many times until the kinetic energy of the charge is exhausted by the photon emissions and the charge comes to rest in the center of a spiral.

So you are right about the polygonal motion (being in a spiral path).

Comment: "This repeats many times until the kinetic energy of the charge is exhausted by the photon emissions and the charge comes to rest in the center of a spiral." this is wrong. In vacuume there is no "coming to rest" , the spiral goes on as long as there is a magnetic field that is why vacuum is necessary in beam lines. the energy loss in detectrors and the spriral becoming a point happens because of interaction of the charged track with the medium. themomentum of the photon is virtual and the scattering is elastic.

Comment: @annav The energy, emitted during the electron deflections (the so brillant photon emission for free electron lasers) has to come somewhere. From what, Anna? What is your suggestion? Additional, the beam line has not only magnets for the particle deflection but also acceleration devices with electric fields.

Comment: elatic scattering means no energy is lost in the center of mass system. Because the magnets are so much more massive then the charged particles, the energy loss in the lab is not measurable. So the charged particle scatters with the field elastically in the center of mass particle/magnet and the spiral remains unchanged as long as there is a field .no electric fields here https://www.alamy.com/fine-beam-of-electrons-moving-in-a-circular-path-while-in-a-uniform-image146608.html , and the spiral is a circle

Comment: @anna to draw the full picture https://imgur.com/gallery/1H4Mi9N there is a cathode and an anode and the electrons make only one circle from which it is impossible to conclude about circles forever. And please explain the source for the photon emissions ( I can see it only from the electrons kinetic energy)

Comment: Yes, the emissions take energy but it is very small with respect to  the momentum which keeps the electron in the $mv^2=BQv/r$ circle in the pictrure., synchrotron radiation.

Comment: https://www.osti.gov/etdeweb/biblio/6898393  I see from this you should not be talking about photons but about classical elecrtromagnetic fields. if you are using the magnetic dipole argument, and it is synchrotron radiation that will, even in vacuum, diminish the track radius  eventually .

Comment: Anna V, thank you for sharing the link. Nice. @annav

Answer (score 0):

I believe the question is much simpler that what current answers try to answer. There seems to be a simple confusion regarding the Lorentz force. As such the force has an effect on the acceleration not the velocity.

$$m\, \vec{a}(t) = \vec{F}_{Magnetic} = q \vec{v}(t) \times \vec{B}$$

This being said if you follow the vector algebra the acceleration will always be point towards the center of the circle and will be always perpendicular to the velocity. Since vector components can be thought of as independent you can see that having a perpendicular acceleration cannot change magnitude of the velocity vector, only its direction. The pythagorean theorem has nothing to say in this regard, since you are not adding vectors here, you could perhaps look at the problem with the time component being discrete and you will see how at every step in time the velocity direction is corrected but not it's length

$$\vec{v}(t+\Delta t) = \vec{v}(t) + \Delta t\, \vec{a}  $$

$$|\vec{v}(t+\Delta t)|^2 = |\vec{v}(t)|^2 + \Delta t^2 |\vec{a}|^2$$

where I have used the fact that acceleration is perpendicular to velocity to get the last expression. Now as you can see, once you take the limit of $\Delta t\rightarrow 0$ the acceleration part falls off extremely quickly and your vector indeed keeps its norm.